# SSH protocol has been blocked and I don't have access to remote git repository

Tags: git, github, ssh, bitbucket

I am living in Iran and SSH has been blocked since yesterday; I need to access to my git repository on bitbucket and github!

Here comes the result of

> ssh -v git@github.com

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.252.131] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/me/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh-0.6.0
debug1: no match: libssh-0.6.0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
    Read from socket failed: Operation timed out
```

Any idea what can I do now?

Comment: github also offers https access... but anyway, that output does not look like access is blocked... In contrary, it says: Connection established"...

Comment: Is using https an option?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608086/git-and-bitbucket-without-ssh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use HTTPS instead or....

Get a free AWS account and launch a micro Linux instance. You then can use it as a proxy to GitHub. You will want to connect to the Lunux server using port 443 or something that isn't blocked for you. Take a look into SSH config if you're running OS X or Linux locally.

An alternative would be to open a VPN or Stunnel between you and the linux server on AWS.

Comment: Thanks, I changed remote url to https. I used both stunnel and open vpn. None of them working. Any how https is still working. I have to find other ways before they block all of secure protocols!

Comment: I doubt port 443 to an SSH proxy would help. If it did, @aakpro could [just use an altssh domain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75390183/241211) for his remotes. In the output he posts, a connection is *established* but negotiation fails. The network owner can block SSH as a protocol without specifying a port. An HTTPS proxy would work like you said. Further experimentation would be needed to see if WireGuard, OpenVPN, private SOCKS5, etc. are blocked.