# How do I store credentials per repository in Git Credential Manager for Windows?

Tags: git, git-credential-manager

I have two GitHub accounts, work and personal, for which I want to **securely** store credentials in Windows 10.

`git config --global credential.helper manager` only sets a single username and password, which conflicts between a repository from my personal account and one from my work account. Both repositories are cloned using HTTPS.

I want to store and access different credentials, probably based on repository username. Is it possible?

I know SSH is an option, but I would like to know how to do it for HTTPS.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48604028/7976758

Answer (score 17):

There are three different ways you can do this, depending on your particular goals and circumstances:

- Put a username in the URL.
- Enable `useHttpPath`.
- Switch to SSH on port `443`.

## Add your username in the URL

On Bitbucket, you can add a username to the HTTPS URL of your remote:

| State | Remote URL |
| --- | --- |
| Before | `https://bitbucket.org/path/repo.git` |
| After | `https://JerryGoyal@bitbucket.org/path/repo.git` |

Since the URL is technically different, you can add both your work and personal forks as remotes for the same repository if you want to. The  technique works on GitHub as well, but other repository hosts may not support it.

## Set `useHttpPath` for the host

Git Credential Manager [can select](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager/blob/main/docs/configuration.md#credentialusehttppath) a credential based on the full URL, rather than sharing them by hostname.

> ### [`credential.useHttpPath`](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager/blob/main/docs/configuration.md#credentialusehttppath)
>
> Tells Git to pass the entire repository URL, rather than just the hostname, when calling out to a credential provider. (This setting [comes from Git itself](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials/#Documentation/gitcredentials.txt-useHttpPath), not GCM.)
>
> Defaults to `false`.

This second method does not work if you want to use multiple remote credentials for the *exact same remote.* But if you have different URLs for separate remotes, it should work fine, even from a single local repository.

### All repositories on the remote host

This is often the most useful mode for `useHttpPath`. To set the option for all Bitbucket remote URLs, run this:

```bash
git config --global credential.https://bitbucket.org.useHttpPath true
```

Git for Windows enables `useHttpPath` for Azure Repos right out of the box. You can see it for yourself in `etc/gitconfig` in your install location.

```ini
[credential "https://dev.azure.com"]
    useHttpPath = true
```

### Just one repository on the remote host

As [rjmunro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3408/rjmunro) notes, you can drop `--global` to use the path for only the current repository. If so, you may as well drop the hostname, too:

```bash
git config credential.useHttpPath true
```

Then, repositories for the host will default to a shared host-credential, but *this* repository will use the full URL path for saving and loading its credential.

### All repositories on your computer

Technically, you can force yourself to separately add credentials for *every single remote repository.* That's needlessly verbose, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48604028/241211) shows how:

```bash
git config --global credential.useHttpPath true
```

## What I really want is `ssh`, but Port 22 is blocked

If you're only asking about HTTPS because you have a firewall problem outside of your control, you might be interested in [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75390183/241211) for using Port 443 for certain Git providers that support it.

Comment: my expectation is to remember both usernames and password in a secure way. if I use useHttpPath I'm being asked for a password each time.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a different helper e.g. [`git-credential-store`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store), which takes an optional parameter for a credential file path. You could set this in the local configuration in each repository, with a different credentials file for each one.

Alternatively, use the suggestion in [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48604028/241211) in [phd's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52222046/241211#comment91410767_52222046) which should work for Git Credential Manager For Windows.

Comment: I specifically asked for a secured way.  git-credential-store save passwords in plain text!

Comment: If you think Git Credential Manager for Windows doesn't also store them in plaintext then you're in for a surprise ;)

Comment: oh is it! then tell me how to see password which is stored using manager? https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows

Comment: [cmdkey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmdkey) lets you do it on the command line, or there's a [programmatic api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincred/) if you're a glutton for punishment

Comment: did u actually try cmdkey? they clearly say on page that "Passwords will not be displayed once they are stored."

Comment: My bad, I'm on mobile and didn't check. Have used CredRead from the api though, or you can also use [git credential fill](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential) on the command line. You have to provide some args on stdin, and you have to do it on cygwin as it doesn't like Windows line endings, and that will print your password on the console. It's all just security through obscurity :(

Answer (score 1):

> More generally, you can use `credential.useHttpPath` to split credential management for multiple repositories run by the same host. <sup>[[‡](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52336920/241211)]</sup>

In that case, use Git 2.27 (Q2 2020), because the parsing of URL for the credential helper has been corrected.

See [commit 4c5971e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4c5971e18a181c68aec03262fb467cb5d21a5b0d) (14 Apr 2020) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a397e9c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a397e9c236b0ff56eb15f32a2a41c852b1e5dd3b), 22 Apr 2020)</sup>

> ### [`credential`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4c5971e18a181c68aec03262fb467cb5d21a5b0d): treat "`?`" and "`#`" in URLs as end of host
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>
>
> It's unusual to see:
>
> ```
> https://example.com?query-parameters
> ```
>
> without an intervening slash, like:
>
> ```
> https://example.com/some-path?query-parameters
> ```
>
> or even:
>
> ```
> https://example.com/?query-parameters
> ```
>
> but it is a valid end to the hostname (actually "authority component") according to [RFC 3986](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.html). Likewise for "`#`".
>
> And `curl` will parse the URL according to the standard, meaning it will contact `example.com`, but our credential code would ask about a bogus hostname with a "`?`" in it.
>
> Let's make sure we follow the standard, and more importantly ask about the same hosts that `curl` will be talking to.
>
> It would be nice if we could just ask curl to parse the URL for us.
> But it didn't grow a URL-parsing API until 7.62, so we'd be stuck with fallback code either way.
> Plus we'd need this code in the main Git binary, where we've tried to avoid having a link dependency on `libcurl`.
>
> But let's at least fix our parser. Moving to `curl`'s parser would prevent other potential discrepancies, but this gives us immediate relief for the known problem, and would help our fallback code if we eventually use `curl`.

---

With Git 2.35 (Q1 2022), credentials and other variable value benefit from the latest of  [RFC 3986](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.html): treating underscores (`_`) as any other URL-valid characters in an URL when matching the per-URL configuration variable names.

See [commit e4c497a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e4c497a1944f035b3e4e947d9518d947d42d40a1) (12 Oct 2021) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 96eca02](https://github.com/git/git/commit/96eca029bf96dd739c0868ed8cf56cdcf1a248f4), 29 Nov 2021)</sup>

> ### [`urlmatch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e4c497a1944f035b3e4e947d9518d947d42d40a1): add underscore to `URL_HOST_CHARS`
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Alex Waite</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Jeff King</sup>
>
> When parsing a URL to normalize it, we allow hostnames to contain only dot ("`.`") or dash ("`-`"), plus brackets and colons for IPv6 literals.
> This matches the old URL standard in [RFC 1738](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.html), which says:
>
> ```ini
> host           = hostname | hostnumber
> hostname       = *[ domainlabel "." ] toplabel
> domainlabel    = alphadigit | alphadigit *[ alphadigit | "-" ] alphadigit
> ```
>
> But this was later updated by [RFC 3986](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.html), which is more liberal:
>
> ```ini
> host        = IP-literal / IPv4address / reg-name
> reg-name    = *( unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims )
> unreserved  = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
> ```
>
> While names with underscore in them are not common and possibly violate some DNS rules, they do work in practice, and we will happily contact them over `http://`, `git://`, or `ssh://`.
> It seems odd to ignore them for purposes of URL matching, especially when the URL RFC seems to allow them.
>
> There shouldn't be any downside here.
> It's not a syntactically significant character in a URL, so we won't be confused about parsing; we'd have simply rejected such a URL previously (the test here checks the url code directly, but the obvious user-visible effect would be failing to match `credential.http://foo_bar.example.com.helper`, or similar config in `http.<url>.*`).
>
> Arguably we'd want to allow tilde ("`~`") here, too.
> There's likewise probably no downside, but I didn't add it simply because it seems like an even less likely character to appear in a hostname.

Answer (score -5):

You **can't** have multiple usernames per host (or URI). As far as I know, SSH is the most straight-forward, as it currently stands, to do what you want to do.

For more information, you can look at VonC's answer to a very similar question as yours. [GitHub: Separate credentials for two accounts on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48466698/10276436)

Comment: The question does not imply using multiple usernames on the same host.